# python code to parallelly run all the queries fetches only the last query during parallel execution

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have tried to write down a python code to parallelly run all the snowflake query that is stored in an excel sheet.

for a trial I have only kept queries that runs and completes in few seconds in the excel sheet. The below python code displays result of only the last query whereas it skips rest all. I'm not sure where im doing wrong . Could somebody please help me out here.

```
from EXCEL_CONNECTION import *
from SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION import *
import pandas
from REMOVE_OUTPUT_FILES import *
import time
start = time.time()


all_rows = list(ws.rows) # to fetch all rows from excel sheet
cur = ctx.cursor()
for row in all_rows[1:40]:
    query = row[2].value
    if_execute = row[3].value
    if if_execute == 'Y':
        try:
            cur.execute_async(query)
            Query_id.append(cur.sfqid)
            #Query_id = scenario
        except:
            print(Query_id," Failed")
        else:
            print(Query_id, "Passed")

        

for id in [Query_id]:
    while ctx.is_still_running(ctx.get_query_status(id)):
    time.sleep(1)
    cur.get_results_from_sfqid(id)
    print(cur.fetchall())
print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: You are overwriting `Query_id` each time through your first loop.  When that loop ends, the only thing left in it is the final result.  If you want to accumulate results, you will need to use `Query_id.append` to create a list of results.

Comment: seems this line of code only checks the last query although it looks like a loop
"for id in [Query_id]:"

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried to use Query_id.append but it throws error as 'Query_id' is not defined and if i'm accumulating all the Query_Id's in a variable how could I use them in while loop. Could you please guide me.
I added the Append syntax in the original code in my question.

Comment: Come on.  Surely you can figure out that, before you can append to a list, you have to create an empty list.  `Query_id = []` before the loop.